# How to normalize a RGB image read from a csv file using Tensorflow?

Tags: scikit-learn, tensorflow

```
  png = tf.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.image.decode_png(png, channels=3)
  image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
```

The images are read and casted to float32. How do I perform a normalization on this?  I have performed normalization on grayscale. But need some help with RGB image.

I thought of doing this

```
def normalized(down):

        norm=np.zeros((600,800,3),np.float32)
        norm_rgb=np.zeros((600,800,3),np.uint8)

        b=rgb[:,:,0]
        g=rgb[:,:,1]
        r=rgb[:,:,2]

        sum=b+g+r

        norm[:,:,0]=b/sum*255.0
        norm[:,:,1]=g/sum*255.0
        norm[:,:,2]=r/sum*255.0
```

But for this above function to work I need to start a sess on the image and then perform numpy operations. 
Could someone help me do this in tensorflow itself?

Comment: if you are considering how to structure your solution, you can use datasets API to add preprocessing steps after import but before gets batched up for training/validation etc.  Similarly, if using queues, you can manipulate decode operations provided by tf.decode_csv before handing off to something like shuffle_batch queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`tf.image.per_image_standardization`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization). It linearly scales image to have zero mean and unit norm.

```
image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
```